# how do we render accent char without any encoding

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0

My input has accent characterslike Í,Â,Ç Á, using xslt version 1.0 I need to render those characters without any change.

For example : 
`input  Í ÇÂME HOME`
`output Í ÇÂME HOME`
I dont want to encode/change those accent characters but 
I am getting output like   `Ã? Ã‡Ã‚ME HOME`

What I have observed is:
`Í is converting to Ã?`
`Ç to Ã‡`
`Â to Ã‚`

If you observe all these characters are converting to capital a, tilde with additional chars`(, ? ‡ )`

Can anyone Please help me
My style sheet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:element name="root">
                      <xsl:value-of select="/../inputpath/msg"/>
                <\xsl:element>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Code used to transform xml

```
public static String transformByXslt(final String input, final String styleSheet,
            final Map<String, String> parameterMap, final ProductMetadata productMetadata,
            final ProductInstance productInstance, final Map<String, Object> daoMap) throws TransformerException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException, ValidationException, NoNeedToRenderException {

        final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(styleSheet
                .getBytes())));

        setParamsForXslt(transformer, parameterMap, productMetadata, productInstance, daoMap);
        transformer.setErrorListener(new PbErrorListener());
        try {
            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(inputStream), new StreamResult(out));
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            if (ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e) != null
                    && ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e).getClass().equals(ValidationException.class)) {
                throw new ValidationException(e);
            } else if (ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e) != null
                    && ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e).getClass().equals(NoNeedToRenderException.class)) {
                throw new NoNeedToRenderException(e);
            } else if (ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e) != null
                    && ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e).getClass().equals(BlankRenditionException.class)) {
                return "";
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        return out.toString("UTF-8");
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like the issue is external to your stylesheet, either an issue with the encoding when loading the source XML or outputting the result XML. What process are you using to transform the XML?

Comment: Thanks for responding .I am using Xalan-Java class `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`

Comment: And could you show us the code you are using to do that?

Comment: I have updated the question.. please check the code given above

Comment: Not entirely sure exactly why it's happening, but the output you're seeing is the result of reading UTF8 encoded text as if it were Western European (Windows), or 'ANSI' as notepad calls it. I'd hazard a guess that your problem is actually when you read the output, rather than with this code.

Comment: what is the coding for input XML? rather.. can you post your input XML (along with header)

Comment: even I feel the same,Flynn1179 But what will be the solution. what exactly I need is, transfer accent characters to normal characters for example `Â to A` `Á to A`  `Í to I` . If the xslt output renders accent chars, then with that output I can transfer accent character to normal characters.

Comment: InfantPro'Aravind', In input XML I am not using any Header. My xml input looks like <artifact> <accentChar>Í ÇÂME HOME</accentChar></artifact>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rupesh, you are treating UTF-8 encoded data as signle-byte coded data or encoding UTF-8 twice. (the

```
out.toString("UTF-8")
```

???)

First step is to figure out, what encoding is your data in and what encoding are you supposed to produce. For instance if you use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), it has a menu "Encoding" where it shows you the current encoding of the file and allows you to change it, see the effect. Tell us what's the story.

You might be after the western european windows ecoding: windows-1252

Check this as well: [the encoding attribute of the XSL output element](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp)

I could give you some sample in C# if you like, but you run Java...

Comment: `This way it helps me` : Open the input file with Notepad++, make sure that the characters look right, then go to the Encoding menu, and select `Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`..Thanks a lot Robert Ševčík - Robajz

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the code.  In your Java code, could you try changing the two places where you have `"UTF-8"` to instead be `"UTF8"` (no hyphen)?  I think I have seen this issue before.

Comment: thanks JLRishe issue is with input not with java code. `Fix`  : Open the input file with Notepad++, make sure that the characters look right, then go to the Encoding menu, and select `Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`